# Rails active admin filter deleted_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to be able to filter through all the soft deleted users in active admin. I have tried the following code but it doesn't seem to be working as expected?

```
filter :deleted_at, :as => :boolean, :collection => {:Yes => nil, :No => ''}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it will not work because it's not correct way to do it:

```
filter :deleted_at, :as => :boolean, :collection => {:Yes => nil, :No => ''}
```

`as: :boolean` is not AA command.

try this:

```
filter :deleted_at, as: :select, collection: [['Yes', nil], ['No', '']]
```

the values is according to you! change it if database contain really boolean fields:

```
filter :deleted_at, as: :select, collection: [['Yes', true], ['No', false]]
```

You can also use scopes to achieve it:

```
scope :deleted, default: true
scope :not_deleted
```

add to your model those scopes:

```
scope :deleted, -> { where('deleted_at is not null') }
scope :not_deleted, -> { where(deleted_at: nil) }
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried your approach but still getting some problem. Basically my deleted_at is either nil or datetime. I want to show all the users with deleted_at: nil when I choose 'Yes' on filter?

Comment: why you don't use scopes?

Comment: Ok I'm new to activeadmin, I'll have a look at that

Comment: I'm getting undefined method `where' for #<ActiveAdmin::ResourceDSL:0x007f9989a9ea00>

Comment: the second ones you should put inside your model

Comment: Incase if i'm not mistaken the first one goes in the admin/user.rb and the second one in the app/models/user.rb?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96038/discussion-between-matanco-and-ray).